# Routing with AngularJS and Spring-Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am having a lot of issues routing my pages with Spring-Boot and AngularJS. Once the index.html page renders I get a 404 error when I click on a new link. AngularJS in loading fine, and the controllers etc are also loading.

Also worth noting I have to use this `<base href="/">` when I run it on my IDE and this `<base href="/personalsite/">` when I package it into a war file on deploy it on tomcat.

index.html

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="SharpVision">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />  
        <title>Drew</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="Drew's personal site" content="Drew" />
        <meta name="author" content="AHthemes" />

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <!--<script src="http://a1alfred.com/sharpvisionbs3/v2/angular/assets/libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>-->
          <!--<script src="http://a1alfred.com/sharpvisionbs3/v2/angular/assets/libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>-->
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
          <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
               filter: none;
            }

          </style>
        <![endif]-->

        <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <ng-include src="'views/structure/navigation.tpl.html'"></ng-include>

        <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>

        <ng-include src="'views/structure/footer.tpl.html'"></ng-include >

        <!--Scripts-->
        <!--<script src="bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="assets/libs/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
...
```

app.config

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: "views/misc/home.tpl.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when('/features/blog',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/blog.tpl.html",
        controller: "BlogController"
    })
    .when('/features/blogpost',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/blog-post.tpl.html",
        controller: "BlogPostController"
    })
    .when('/features/portfolio',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/portfolio.tpl.html",
        controller: "PortfolioController"
    })
    .when('/features/portfolioitem',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/portfolio-item.tpl.html",
        controller: "PortfolioItemController"
    })
    .when('/features/gallery',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/gallery.tpl.html",
        controller: "GalleryController"
    })
    .when('/features/404',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/404.tpl.html",
        controller: "404Controller"
    })
    .when('/features/500',{
        templateUrl: "views/features/500.tpl.html",
        controller: "500Controller"
    })
    .when('/contact',{
        templateUrl: "views/misc/contact.tpl.html",
        controller: "ContactController"
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Once the page loads I select gallery:

[image: http://localhost:8080/features/portfolioitem]

at: `http://localhost:8080/features/portfolioitem`

which give me a 404:

[image: 404 error]

However all this ONLY happens when I create a war file and deploy it on Tomcat. On my intellij IDE all I have to do it change `<base href="/personalsite/">` to `<base href="/">` and it works fine.

It appears once the application starts loads everything fine but handles the routing through Spring's `@RestController` so I tried this:

```
    //try mapping to contact and gallery and see what happens
    @RequestMapping(value = "/features/portfolioitem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String galleryPage(){
        System.out.println("HIT HIT HIT HIT HIT!!!");

        return "personalsite/features/portfolioitem";
    }
```

[image]

`galleryPage()` renders a page but just the String `personalsite/features/portfolioitem` on the page.

---------------------------UPDATE 1------------------------------------

```
I decided to see if I could use Spring-boot `@RestController` to route my pages but that was unsuccessful. This is how I did it:

 //try mapping to contact and gallery and see what happens
    @RequestMapping(value = "/features/portfolioitem", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String galleryPage(){
        System.out.println("HIT HIT HIT HIT HIT!!!");

        return "views/features/portfolioitem";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String indexPage(){
        System.out.println("I be in here too");


        return "index";
    }
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

    @Bean
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/webapp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

This this only renders the string of whatever the method returns and Angular doe not load.

---------------------Update 2----------------------------

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

 <Service name="Catalina">

<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

 <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>



</Server>
```

--------------------Update 3------------------------------

I added `server.contextPath=/personalsite/` to my `application.properties`

I then change `<base href="/">` to `this is good because now my IDE is doing the same thing as tomcat. Index.html will render at`http://localhost:8081/personalsite/#/`BUT once I click a link I get a blank page, for example`http://localhost:8081/features/portfolioitem`but`personalsite` is missing from the path. I add that and I get the following page:

[image]

Comment: When using html5mode you have to make sure your server always returns you index. Is that the case? Did you check the ui-router page? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: What do your Tomcat configurations look like? If seems to me that your application's base path is not being configured correctly with Tomcat. Specifically what do your servlet mapping settings look like?

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I am using `ng-route` and I just removed `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and that sadly didn't work. I also tried to add the configuration to `server.xml` that did not do it either.

Comment: @PeterKirby please see update 2

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular

Answer (score 0):

## Update 1:

You should add 'server.contextPath=/' to your 'application.properties' file.

## Update 2:

You need to remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation if you want Spring to resolve your view, rather than return a string, from your `galleryPage` method.

## Update 3:

If your entire application is a single page application, with embedded templates, and you want your application, when refreshed on any valid path (like '/features/portfolioitem') to render index.html, you need to route every request to your index method. Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexPage(){
    System.out.println("I be in here too");


    return "index";
}
```

This should load your index.html for all URLS. It is then up to your application to determine if the URL is valid.

Also, make sure you have `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` set in your app.

Comment: No that did not work. I even tried `server.contextPath=/personalsite` too

Comment: Are you using a web.xml file? If so, can you post it?

Comment: I am using angularJS so angular will configure my views on the frontend. I use spring to catch something I light needed submitted to my database like: so `@RequestMapping(value = "/sendForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getForm(Model model){
        System.out.println("In get request");
        model.addAttribute("contact", new Contact());
        return "contact";
    }`

Comment: At least from what I read that is how it works together. There is something that happens when I create a `war` file that messes up my paths. However even if I correct it in my browser it gives me spring-boot error page. I guess that is a step up from a 404 at least.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394493/spring-mvc-configuration-enable. I still think the problem is that you are not configuring your servlet's context path to be equal to '/personalsite'.

Comment: Please see update 3. Thank you for your help. I have been at this for about a week.

Comment: @Drew1208 Added some updates. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I tried all three things you mentioned and just tried them all again. On "Update 3" it is still returning a string and I removed `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108966/discussion-between-peter-kirby-and-drew1208).

Comment: Using Update 3 gives this error: Circular view path [index.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.html] again